# Elegant way to debug n-tier from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Just wondering if there is any easy way to start a debugging session that lauches the server **and** the client by simply pressing F5.

As it stands I have to F5 to debug the server, then find the client project and right click->Debug, which is a bit fiddly.

Any tips to get this to work more smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to: Set Multiple Startup Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx) on MSDN.